# Can someone suggest What is the best form plugin in wordpress to relate my requirements?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

**Front End - Form**

Name:

Email:

Services: Drop Down (If select any service then open sub-drop down)

Another Drop Down for sub service

Attached Multiple images attached function

Message:

Preview Form & Submit

---

**Back End - Form**

All forms manage through admin panel

All forms receive in admin panel

Admin panels have the option to change form status like pending, hold, completed etc
and also add comment to each custom form.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Formidable forms and see if that might be a good solution for you